# If Nighthowler is attached as an Enchantment to a Creature, what different things can it do?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-bestow

1. Do you add the Power and Toughness of [Nighthowler](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=373564) to the Creature's Power and Toughness?
2. If the Creature is tapped, while the Nighthowler is attached to it, can the Nighthowler both attack or block at another Creature?

Answer (score 3):

When you cast a card for its bestow cost; it becomes an Aura Enchantment spell; and does not act as a creature in any way. So [Nighthowler](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Nighthowler) can never attack nor block while it is attached to another creature as an aura.

1. Nighthowler does not have a power or toughness while it is an aura. You add +X/+X to the enchanted creature, where X is the number of creature cards in all graveyards. This is unrelated to the fact that this is also Nighthowler's strength when Nighthowler is a creature; it's simply because it says that that is the enchanted creature's strength.
2. No, Nighthowler cannot attack nor block while it is an aura enchantment.

If the creature that Nighthowler is enchanting leaves the battlefield, Nighthowler will become a regular creature on the battlefield.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the reason you add +X/+X to the enchanted creature's P/T is because Nighthowler says so right on the card: "Enchanted creature gets +X/+X," and has nothing to do with the fact that Nighthowler would have power and toughness X/X if it were a creature.